# Doctrine 2 ArrayCollections - am I missing something?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a bidirectional many-to-one relationship.  Let's go with `Foo` and `Bar`.  `Foo` has the following:

```
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bar", mappedBy="foo", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $bars;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bars = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $bars
     */
    public function setBars($bars)
    {
        $this->bars = $bars;
    }

    /**
     * @param Bar $bar
     */
    public function addBar(Bar $bar)
    {
        $this->bars->add($bar);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBars()
    {
        return $this->bars;
    }
}
```

And `Bar`:

```
class Bar
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Foo", inversedBy="bars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="foo_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $foo;

    /**
     * @param Foo $foo
     */
    public function setFoo(Foo $foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    /**
     * @return Foo
     */
    public function getFoo()
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}
```

Okay, so with the classes above, when I write:

```
$foo = new Foo();

$bar1 = new Bar();
$bar2 = new Bar();

$foo->addBar($bar1);
$foo->addBar($bar2);
```

And try to persist, I get an error about how each `Bar`'s foo property is null:

[image]

Similarly, if I flip it around to:

```
$foo = new Foo();

$bar1 = new Bar();
$bar2 = new Bar();

$bar1->setFoo($foo);
$bar2->setFoo($foo);
```

I can persist, but then my `Foo`s newly generated `PersistentCollection` for that property is empty:

[image]

Is this intended behavior?  I'm used to other ORMs on different platforms wiring up the bidirectional relationship upon assignment, so I'm not sure if this is normal for Doctrine/PHP, or if my annotations are messed up (which the error message above leads me to believe).

So, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to persist Foo before you call setFoo?

Comment: No change.  `PersistentCollection` remains empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the two sides of the association, for instance

```
/**
 * @param Bar $bar
 */
public function addBar(Bar $bar)
{
    if(!$this->bars->contains($bar)) {
        $this->bars->add($bar);
        $bar->setFoo($this);
    }
}
----
/**
 * @param Foo $foo
 */
public function setFoo(Foo $foo)
{
    if($this->foo !== $foo) {
        $this->foo = $foo;
        $foo->addBar($this);
    }
}
```

At the moment your only setting one side of the association and Doctrine does not do the rest for you.

If you don't want to modify your add/remove methods you have to

```
 $bar->setFoo($foo)
 $foo->addBar($bar)
```

Everytime you want to add a foo or a bar

EDIT:

If you want to use only one side to do all the operation, read about [owning/inverse side](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html). Maybe it could help with your problem. But I'm not sure it will do the correct bidir link between your entities.

Comment: I think I'm on the right track.  `Bar` is actually an association table between a many-to-many relationship of `Foo` and `Baz`, which contains some metadata.  Right now, it's giving me an error about how `Bar` doesn't have an identity of its own.  It contains the foreign keys of `Foo` and `Baz`, but doesn't have its own ID.  I'm not sure if I should just give it an auto-incremented ID of its own, or if I can get it to recognize the foreign ID combo as its own identity.  Sorry I didn't mention it before.  I'm operating under a NDA.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html), @KevinM1. Does it help?

Comment: Unfortunately, the error persists.  Error message is: Entity of type Bar has identity through a foreign entity Foo, however this entity has no identity itself. You have to call EntityManager#persist() on the related entity and make sure that an identifier was generated before trying to persist 'Bar'.  In case of Post Insert ID Generation (such as MySQL Auto-Increment or PostgreSQL SERIAL) this means you have to call EntityManager#flush() between both persist operations.

Comment: The error is explicit. You will have to do `new Foo; persist; flush;` then add some Bar. If Doctrine says this I don't think there is any workaround. Or you can add an id not related to Foo or Baz.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is that you are not setting Foo in Bar when you add a Bar.

To auto set that you can do the following (I've also added a check to see if the Bar has already been added and a return to chain set's)..

```
/**
 * Add bar
 *
 * @param Bar $bar
 * @return $this
 */
public function addBar(Bar $bar)
{
    if (!$this->bars->contains($bar)) {
        $this->bars->add($bar);
        $bar->setFoo($this)
    }

    return $this;
}
```

You should probably get rid of the `setBars` as I can see that causing an issue if you used set but didn't use an array collection.

Also you should add a remove bar so you don't have get, remove, and then reset every time, like..

```
/**
 * Remove bar
 *
 * @param Bar $bar
 * @return $this
 */
public function removeBar(Bar $bar)
{
    if ($this->bars->contains($bar)) {
        $this->bars->removeElement($bar);
        $bar->setFoo(null);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Which would mean your `setFoo` would need to be able to accept a null value..

```
/**
 * Set foo
 *
 * @param Foo $foo
 */
public function setFoo(Foo $foo = null)
{
    $this->foo = $foo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting is telling that an entity can't be persisted without filling the `id` field. Also, it looks like you are missing `id` field in your Foo entity.

Anyway, the `id` field is probably already in your database (autogenerated by Doctrine), but no autoincrement is set so filling it manually is mandatory before persist.

Try adding the following code in your entities:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The @Id is defined above the `protected $foo;` and it is a valid solution.

Comment: doctrine uses the ``auto`` strategy by default and ``@ORM\Id()`` is valid

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `addBar` function. you missed the back ref. from `bar` entity to the `foo` entity

```
/**
* @param Bar $bar
*/
public function addBar(Bar $bar)
{
    $bar->setFoo($this);
    $this->bars->add($bar);
}
```